# Conditional rendering of button on a record detail page in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button

I am working on the following scenario:

We have a custom object `Application__c` which has a picklist called `Status__c`(Draft, In Progress, More Info Needed, Completed)`. Whenever Application record's Status is changed to "More Info" a Button/Link needs to be displayed to the User in the record's detail page, which on click navigates the User to a new record(ApplInfo__c) creation page where ApplInfo__c is a child object of Application__c and on entering the details in ApplInfo__c record and saved, the same should be linked to its parent Application__c record. Any pointers/sample code on how to achieve this in Lightning is really helpful.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using two approaches:

**First Approach:**

1. We can create a lightning component in which we will have the custom button and the logic for the new record creation.
2. Add above component on the record page of `Application__c` object and use component `visibility` feature of the `lightning App builder` to make button visible only when the value of `status__c` field is 'More Info'.

Use this approach if you want to perform some custom logic other record creation

**Second Approach:**

Because `Application__c` is the parent of `AppInfo__c`, so in the lightning app builder add the `related list` of `AppInfo__c` on the `Application__c` record page with a custom `visibility` filter for `status__c` field. So that you can use standard list button to `create` the related records.

i would prefer this if you don't have any custom logic for record creation.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways with which you can accomplish this. Each comes with their own pros and cons:-

1. Use Record Types to display different page layouts based on 'Status__c' picklist. Based on this field you can create a workflow rule to flip the record type whenever Status__c changes to "More Info" and vice versa. So users will see the button when status is "More Info" and won't see it if value is something else.
   The only downside is the number of artifacts/components you will have to create and maintain to achieve this.
2. You can create a formula field on the object to show a link which navigates to the object creation page. You can create a quick action on the object to display this link and put it on the lightning record page's detail tab or you may create a new tab to add the quick action and use component visibility to control the display of tab. The downside of it will be the link will be displayed always on the top of the detail tab
3. You can put the formula field on page layout directly as well. But when the status is not "More Info" then still the formula field will show on the layout